# hardwareAccelerated animation in Android 2.2

Tags: android, animation, gpu, acceleration

is there any way to do run animation on the GPU when writing an app for Android 2.2 and up
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed try using [GlSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html), it is supported from android 1.6

Comment: can you be a bit more specific ? how can i use this for animation ?

Comment: There is no shortcuts here, you just need to learn it all. It is a huge world called OpenURL, you can do any animation you like with it. Perhaps you should Google for some tutorial in the subject. [This is one I found](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/).